# Load Javascript with php ontent

Tags: function, load, loading, reload

I have a problem and I hope you can help.
I will explain the problem first: I have an HTML file, and when the page loads, it calls up content from the PHP page.

The HTML page contains JavaScript files at the end. The part  loaded in the PHP page does not work and I had to load the JavaScript files in the PHP page to work.

The problem  when loading JavaScript files in PHP page, some functions are broken in other parts of the HTML page.

I think there is a conflict when load JavaScript files repeatedly to same page. How can I load JavaScript files only for the part whose content was load in the PHP file?

I put a simple page code explaining the problem here :

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="main">
here main content
</div>

<div id="php">

</div>



<!--  Main jQuery  -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/slick.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#php').load('get_data.php'); 

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```